# Ext Prompt show value entered on re-prompt

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have the following function using the Ext message box prompt:

```
var prompt = function () {
        Ext.Msg.prompt("Number", "", function (btn, text) {
            if (btn == "ok") {
                if ((![0-9][2-8]$/.test(text)) && (!/^[2-9].test(text))) {
                    alert("Please enter a valid number");
                    prompt();
                } else {
                    });
                    // success code  }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

This works exactly the way I want it EXCEPT it doesn't display the text entered in the text box when re-prompted on fail. Is there a way to pass in the 'text' variable into the re-call of the prompt function? Or does this just need a total re-architecture? What I'd like is the "please enter a valid number" alert to appear and then have the prompt display again with the already entered text.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that should do it. But you should took a look at the [API](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.MessageBox-method-prompt). The last argument is the default value for the textfield within

```
var prompt = function (val) {
        Ext.Msg.prompt("Number", "", function (btn, text) {
            if (btn == "ok") {
                if ((![0-9][2-8]$/.test(text)) && (!/^[2-9].test(text))) {
                    alert("Please enter a valid number");
                    prompt(text);
                } else {
                    });
                    // success code  }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }, this, false, val || '');
    };
```